# Numeric keyboard is not working in android 4.0.3 and above versions

Tags: android, jquery, html, cordova

I am working on android phonegap application. My phonegap version is 2.2.0. I am using `<input type="number">` to open numeric keyboard..It is working fine on versions below 4.0.3 but when I test my application on an android 4.0.3 device, the numeric keyboard is not working.

I also tried to replace `<input type="number">` to ** and also added   `<meta name = "format-detection" content = "telephone=no">` line on head but it's still not working.

Comment: not working means? not showing or cannot input numbers?

Comment: means its opening simple keypad with alphabetic keys..Numeric keypad is not opening directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support with Android is qualified as buggy :-(

See [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/inputs_mobile.html#t04).